# Creating Synchronized static singleton Map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, hashmap

I have enough knowledge on creating Synchronized static objects.
However for a Map (Collection) in Java,

I found default implementations in Java individually (one for Synchronized list and one for for Singleton map).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K, V)

I am thinking of getting the desired result by following implementation

```
Map<K,V> initMap = new HashMap<K,V>(); 
Map<K,V> syncSingMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(Collection.singletonMap(initMap));
```

Am i making right sense? Because documentation at oracle shows some warning on this

```
It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views:

 Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
  ...
 Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
  ...
 synchronized(m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
  Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
  while (i.hasNext())
      foo(i.next());
 }

 Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior
```

How about using ConcurrentMap over this.

Requriement: static synchronized singleton map which will be used by tons of threads for some processing operations

**UPDATE**

After going through few articles, found that ConcurrentMap is much preferable than HashMap in multi-thread environment
http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-7-hashmap-vs

Comment: a singletonMap is for a single element, not a singelton instance of a map.

Comment: you're probably best off with the ConcurrentMap (i assume you will be modifying the map?)

Comment: yes. I will be modifying the map once the thread has done it's job by taking something from map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ConcurrentMap if you are using Java 6+:

```
public class MapHolder {
    public static final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> A_MAP = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
}
```

Comment: since it's static variable, it will be singleton right!
but what' the significance of final. {i am still in learning stage in multi-threading}

Comment: final just means that someone else can't assign a new concurrent map to that variable.  It can only be assigned to once!

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use `ConcurrentHashMap` for **performance** reasons also, `synchronizedMap` will cause `lock` on the map instance and will reduce the performance. But in `ConcurrentHashMap` there is **highly optimized algorithms** for achieving high level of concurrency.

**For an example ConcurrentHashMap has lock for each Hash Bucket and so multiple threads can even update the map.**

`ConcurrentHashMap` is better than `synchronizedMap`.

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.singletonMap` returns an immutable `Map` with exactly one entry, not a "singleton" in the sense of "only one exists in your application."  (If you use `Collections.singletonMap`, there's no need to synchronize it, since it's unmodifiable.)